# What is the `android.util.secutil` package about?

Tags: java, android

*(I'm not sure whether [android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com) would be a better fit, but since it's a question about Java internals I thought SO would be a better choice. Feel free to migrate.)*

Background: I accidentially deleted `/system/apps/Mms.apk` on my Samsung Galaxy Ace (GT-S5830, running Android 2.3.6). Since I don't have a backup I tried replacing it from a stock ROM. However, the `Mms.apk` from the stock ROM crashes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  654): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.secutil.Log
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at com.android.mms.MmsConfig.init(MmsConfig.java:104)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at com.android.mms.MmsApp.onCreate(MmsApp.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3276)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime(  654):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  160): Process com.android.mms has crashed too many times: killing!
```

I couldn't find any information online regarding the `android.util.secutil` package, aside from other similar stacktraces. Hence:

> **What is the `android.util.secutil` package about?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at snippets from 4 years ago, the package contains:

- A `Log` class - looks like nothing more than a bunch of logging utilities bundled toghether. To be used with `LogSwitcher`
- `LogSwitcher` - can tell you if you're currently showing global log/security debug log/security error log/etc.
- `Slog` - similar methods to `Log`, but each one does a check and prints only if a particular log is active(e.g. security error)
- `SmartParser` - parsing class for `SmartParsingData`
- `SmartParsingData` - storage class for date info, email info, phone num info, url info
- `SmartPatterns` - storage class for various date/other patterns. Jan is 1, Dec is 12. Things like that.

That more or less covers the package. Looks fairly generic overall.